# C# VSTO getting pathname of current PowerPoint Presentation

Tags: c#, powerpoint, vsto

I'm getting crazy, should be a easy topic, but in my AddIn I'm not able to access the ActivePresentation.FullName or other attributes of the ActivePresentation Object.

```
PowerPoint.Application aPowerPoint = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
PowerPoint.Presentation oPresentation = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation;
```

oPresentation contains attributes like FullName, Path, Name etc. - but doesn't matter which I want to use, I'm getting following error:
'Presentation' does not contain a definition for 'FullName' and no accessible extension method 'FullName' accepting a first argument of type 'Presentation' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What is wrong here?

Should be possible to get via Globals.ThisAddin.Application.ActivePresentation.Name etc. but also this ends in above error.
Any ideas?

Comment: If it's a new presentation that has not been saved yet then such error is likely.

Comment: Try to open a saved presentation in PowerPoint and get all these properties. Do you still get errors like that?